# Reflector not injected to my custom guard in nestjs

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I have created a guard in a separate module for checking feature flags as below

```
@Injectable()
export class FeatureFlagGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(
        private reflector: Reflector,
        private featureFlagService: FeatureFlagService
    ) {}

    async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean> {
        const featureKey = this.reflector.get<string>(
            FEATURE_FLAG_DECORATOR_KEY,
            context.getHandler()
        );

        if (!featureKey) {
            return true;
        }
        return await this.featureFlagService.isFeatureEnabled(featureKey);
    }
}
```

and here is my decorator

```
import { SetMetadata } from '@nestjs/common';

export const FEATURE_FLAG_DECORATOR_KEY = 'FEATURE_FLAG';
export const FeatureEnabled = (featureName: string) =>
    SetMetadata(FEATURE_FLAG_DECORATOR_KEY, featureName);
```

Then in appModule I provided the FeatureFlagGuard as below

```
    providers: [
        {
            provide: APP_GUARD,
            useClass: FeatureFlagGuard
        }
    ]
```

Then in my controller

```
    @FeatureEnabled('FEATURE1')
    @Get('/check-feature-flag')
    checkFeatureFlag() {
        return {
            date: new Date().toISOString()
        };
    }
```

When I run the code I get this error, since the `reflector` is injected as null into my service

```
[error] [ExceptionsHandler] Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')
```

Not sure what I missed

Comment: If your `FeatureFlagService` `REQUEST` scoped?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel not sure, it should be like Role example on nestjs site

Comment: @JayMcDoniel feature flag service will downloads a json file and then reads the file and checks if the flag is true or false

(which is not implemenetd yet)

Comment: @JayMcDoniel I removed featureFlagService from constructor and reflector get injected correctly

Comment: @JayMcDoniel `Reflector` can't be injected with `REQUEST` scoped service?

Comment: @AmrSalama That's not true. Enhancers and request scoped providers don't necessarily play well together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @jayMcDoniel to give me a clue

The issue was the `FeatureFlagService` was not exported from the module. When I exported it the issue is resolved